# How do I form the String[] for a UNIX command in Java?

Tags: java, unix

I'm trying to delete all the files with a .mp3 extension on my computer, and I want to do this with Java.  I figured out this:

```
String[] cmd = {theCommandStuff};
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

My only trouble is forming the cmd String[]. What is the correct format?

Comment: Do you know how would your unix command look like? Just asking hoping that you have only problem with putting in it `cmd` array.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use the [`delete()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete()) method on the `File` class? It would be faster than shelling out and running `rm`, and more portable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you would execute a simple UNIX command ...

```
    String[] cmd = {"ls", "-l", "somedir"};
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

If you need to run a pipeline, use file redirection, or other "fancy shell stuff" in the command line, then the easy way is to let the shell take care of it; e.g.

```
    String[] cmd = {"sh", "-c", "ls -lR somedir | grep foobar"};
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

As for what command to run to delete all ".mp3" files ... that's better asked on http://superuser.com or http://askubuntu.com.

(Hint: use the "find" command ... "man find" )

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html), you might to try a [SimpleFileVisitor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/SimpleFileVisitor.html) - that is something like this;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.PathMatcher;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Question {
  public static class Finder extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

    private List<File>        files = new ArrayList<File>();
    private final PathMatcher matcher;

    public List<File> getFiles() {
        return files;
    }

    Finder(String pattern) {
        matcher = FileSystems.getDefault()
                .getPathMatcher("glob:" + pattern);
    }

    // Compares the glob pattern against
    // the file or directory name.
    void find(Path file) {
        Path name = file.getFileName();
        if (name != null && matcher.matches(name)) {
            files.add(name.toFile());
        }
    }

    // Prints the matches to standard out.
    void done() {
        for (File f : files) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Matched file " + f.getCanonicalPath());
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Matched: " + files.size());
        System.out.flush();
    }

    // Invoke the pattern matching
    // method on each file.
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
        find(file);
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    // Invoke the pattern matching
    // method on each directory.
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir,
            BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
        find(dir);
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) {
        System.err.println(exc);
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Finder f = new Finder("*.mp3");
    Path startingDir = Paths.get("/"); // e.g. C:/ on Windows.
    try {
        Files.walkFileTree(startingDir, f);
        List<File> fileList = f.getFiles();
        for (File file : fileList) {
            file.delete();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    f.done();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)`, cmd could just be a String, and that would just run the command. In the case where it takes an array, it will execute the command with the first element of the array, and the rest of the elements of the array are just command line arguments. Example:

```
String cmdArg[2] = new String[];
cmdArg[0] = new String("/bin/vi");
cmdArg[1] = new String("someFile);
```

In terms of your application, a Java program's main function is defined as such:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { ... }
```

And so, that args array represents once passed in the command line. For instance, if you run your program like this:

```
java exampleProgram Hello Dear World
```

args[] would be:

```
args[0] = Hello
args[1] = Dear
args[2] = World
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Now, you could use Process package to execute shell commands. You could also choose to mainipulate files directly. I recommend looking a the `java.nio.Path` package, Apache Commons IO package, and if you want a more sophisticated way to parse command line arguments, the Apache Commons cli package.

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in the comments, I think it would be better to use the Java APIs to delete files. But if you want to know how to do it, it's best to just try it out:

```
$ cat Run.java
public class Run {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args).waitFor();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

$ javac Run.java

$ touch /tmp/foo

$ ls /tmp/foo
/tmp/foo

$ java Run rm /tmp/foo

$ ls /tmp/foo
ls: /tmp/foo: No such file or directory
```

The arguments passed to `java Run` would become a `String[]` like `{ "rm", "/tmp/foo" }`.

So the 0th element in the `String[]` is going to be the command to run, and each argument thereafter is going to be its arguments.

Be careful because this does not use the shell, so you will not get glob expansion (`rm *.mp3` will not work without invoking the shell, as mentioned in another answer).

You also need to be careful when running commands that output to standard output or standard error. Invoking commands in this way requires that you read their standard input and output streams; if you fail to do this, the process may fill up its buffers and "hang".

Again, it's a lot simpler to call [`delete()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29).